# Custom order the bar of histogram using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a graph:

[image]

I want the graph xticks' orders to be customized. There are more than 20 graphs to be made from the data. Is there any way I can customize orders of the bar in the histogram with reference to the list.

```
bar_data=["N/A", "I would probably talk to Yield Advisory", "I would definitely talk to Yield Advisory", "I already use Yield Advisory for this","I might talk to Yield Advisory"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, here is the solution https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/ticks_and_spines/custom_ticker1.html#sphx-glr-gallery-ticks-and-spines-custom-ticker1-py

You just need to change this piece of code the way you want.

```
plt.xticks(x, ('Bill', 'Fred', 'Mary', 'Sue'))
```